# time command with flags running application with flags

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, time, mpi

Im trying to time my little program, which uses MPI and I want the output in a file.

The command Im trying: `time --output=rt.txt mpirun -np 2 a.out`.  But the flags for `time`and  `mpirun` seem to  clash.

Any ideas how this might work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about this ? From the man page for the *binary* `time`

> Options to time must appear on the command line before COMMAND. 
>   Anything on the command line after COMMAND is passed as arguments to
>   COMMAND

Which `time` are you using ? Note there's a built-in shell `time`, and a separate binary. I suspect you need to use the separate binary rather than the built-in. Just specify it as `/usr/bin/time` (or wherever it's installed)

Comment: Im usig the built-in `time` from the bash in Ubuntu.

Comment: I suspect that's your problem

Comment: This statement in the manpage cause me to think the syntax should be like this

Comment: time mpirun -np 2 a.out >rt.txt

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the time binary, have you heard of the `MPI_Wtime` function? Timing your application with `MPI_Wtime` can produce more accurate results of the execution time of your entire parallel job. You can use `MPI_Wtime` as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
int main(void) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // Get the program start time after all processes have initialized and synchronized
    double start_time = MPI_Wtime();

    // Do parallel processing here...
    sleep(1);

    // Synchronize all the processes again and find out the total execution time
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    double execution_time = MPI_Wtime() - start_time;

    // Print the execution time from the root process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        printf("Execution time %lf\n", execution_time);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

This program should print off something close this ->
Execution time 1.0

Comment: Wow, thanks!I did know about MPI_Wtime, but for the above task I only needed a rough comparison between executions with different number of proccessors (-np x). So,an exact timing wasnt really needed. But thanks a lot of the code. Will surely use it sometime!